# User registration in gatsby js

Tags: dynamic, static, registration, gatsby

is their a way to let a website developed using Gatsby js, have user registration, user can have a profile and edit it, and user can add new article or item to the website ?

I know gatsby is static site generator. but I'm wondering if I can use Gatsby as a solution for such web application, and if not what are the tools I need to include to make it work ?

thanks.

Comment: Check out [gatsby-firebase-authentication](https://github.com/rwieruch/gatsby-firebase-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are getting downvoted.

Apart from [the comment by @fabian-schultz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272213/user-registration-in-gatsby-js#comment85553015_49272213), the keyword is you are looking for I believe is CMS.

Basically you just want some dynamic content in your website which is generated by a static site generator.

There are a lot of choices. For example, you can follow [the official tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/netlify-cms/) to use Netlify CMS with Gatsby.

Hope it's enough to get you started.